# Where is content saved during offline lazyloading?

Tags: web-scraping, lazy-loading

I'm trying to scrape all products from [this webpage](https://www.bunnings.com.au/products/tools/power-tools)'s 1st page that is apparently using offline lazyloading. At first, it only shows/loads 12 products, but when you scroll a bit, it shows additionally 24 products by filling up the `<div class="lazyload-placeholder"></div>` HTML element without making a single request, meaning, it already has them saved somewhere. My question is where?

Answer (score 0):

The lazy image data is actually already in the page source!

One way to figure this out is load the page in your browser, find and copy image url. Then open page source and ctrl+f for your image:

[image]

Here you can see it's under `picture` tag. You can use css selector `picture>source::attr(data-srcset)` to find all lazy images.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I don't think the not-yet-loaded products' pictures are included. Let me break it down: there's a total of 56 `<source>` tags within a `<picture>` tag with a `data-srcset` attribute. The first 15 of them are pictures of people, the next 17 of them are pictures of categories (compressors, batteries, drills,...), and the last 24 of them are 12 already-loaded/shown products, each having 1 picture of itself and 1 picture of the company making them. There's no sight of pictures (or any other info such as links or titles) of the not-yet-loaded products.